# MEAN app with unauthenticated and authenticated index.html

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I am developing an app using the MEAN stack.

I have a public side to the site and private and using Angularjs there is one index.html which includes all the js file includes which i dont want them showing if on the unauthenticated part of the site.

So was wondering is it possible to have two files i.e. index.html and indexpub.html which i can use and include the relevant files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably better to have admin stuff in a separate folder, for example, /supersecretadminarea/. but yes, it's possible.

Comment: would i have a seperate index.html in that folder structure. If so would this need to be added to the routing?

Comment: you would have a separate routing, it would be like an entirely separate angular app either way.

Comment: Note that both ways still don't prevent the users form downloading and viewing the unauthenticated parts of the site. There's nothing you can do with angular/html/css alone to prevent that.